# How to prefetch data from firebase database then present the view with those datas in Textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to prefetch username from firebase database then show it in a textfield when the view is presented with no delay. 
Problem is I can't seem to prefetch data from the database before the view is presented.

I tried having an if statement inside the observe single view that says if self.username != nil then configure the view (Moved the view did load configure view functions inside this if statement). This almost did  what I wanted but it showed the animation of the view loading and waited a couple of seconds till it got the textfield loaded with it data. Trying to eliminate the delay and make it instantly load with the view.

Also tried to add func setData { userTextField.text = username } and call it in getData in observe, still 2 second delay.

Note: 
ProfileController file self.present AccountInfoController File

Extension File:

```
    extension UIView {
func labelTextContainerView(view: UIView, label: UILabel,_ textField: UITextField) -> UIView {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    label.textColor = UIColor.mainBlue()

    label.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 9)
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    if (textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true) {
        label.isHidden = true
    }


    view.addSubview(textField)
    //textField.textColor = .black
    textField.anchor(top: label.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)
    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    let separatorView = UIView()
    separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.87, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(separatorView)
    separatorView.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.75)

    return view
}    

}


extension UITextField {
func editableTextField(withPlaceolder placeholder: String, someText: String?, enableEditing: Bool) -> UITextField {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.borderStyle = .none
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    if (enableEditing == false) {
        tf.isEnabled = enableEditing
        tf.isUserInteractionEnabled = enableEditing
        tf.alpha = 0.5
    }

    tf.text = someText
    tf.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1)])
    return tf
}
}
```

AccountInfoController FILE :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class AccountInfoController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Properties
var ref = Database.database().reference()
var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var username: String?
var userLabel = UILabel()

lazy var userContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view.labelTextContainerView(view: view, label: userLabel, userTextField)
}()

lazy var userTextField: UITextField = {
    userLabel.text = "Username"
    userLabel.isHidden = false
    let tf = UITextField()
    return tf.editableTextField(withPlaceolder: "Username", someText: self.username?.lowercased(), enableEditing: false)
}()

//MARK: - Init
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getUserData()

    //print(self.username)

    configureViewComponents()
    configureViewLabel()
}

func getUserData() {
    user.child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let userName = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
        print(userName)
        self.username = userName
    }

}

// MARK: - Helper Functions

func configureViewLabel() {
    //some code
}

func configureViewComponents() {
    //some code

    view.addSubview(userContainerView)
    userContainerView.anchor(top: emailContainerView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 60)

    //some code
}
}
```

Expectation: When presenting AccountInfoController I want the textfield to have the username of the current user without waiting for database to fetch the data, **I expect the database to prefetch the username.**

Current Results: The code above doesn't even show the username in the textfield after database fetches it. unless the if statement mentioned above is added therefore there is a 2 seconds delay.

Comment: Quite a few things should be addressed. The getUserData() returns immediately, and inside it you are setting username, but not changing the textfield. You should add a didSet {} in the username. And change the textlabel.text on the main thread. 
That should update the view with a short delay. Other than that, you would need to prefetch the data.

Comment: @arvidurs I understand that and one of my tries was that I added an if statement right after self.username = userName in getUserData() function that states if (self.username != nil) { configureViewComponents(); configureViewLabel() } and I removed those two configure methods from viewDidLoad(). And that worked with a delay. I don't want this delay. I am asking for how to prefetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found an answer to my problem.
All that needed to be done is declaring a public variable for all classes to use, then at the Home page where your app first load after signing in fetch the data from the database and assign them to the public variables.

This solved my issue.

In profile controller file:
Outside the class:

```
public var username: String?
```

inside the class:

I moved the getUserData() func from AccountInfoController to ProfileController

inside the viewDidLoad():

```
getUserData()
```

Finally when initializing the text field I assigned the text to be the public variable.